# Visual Studio compiler uses std by default

Tags: visual-c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << abs(-5.3) << "\n";
}
```

When compiled with g++, it prints 5, which I get—overloaded abs lies in `std`, and I did not use it.

But if I use Visual Studio compiler (19.14.26433), result is 5.3.

If I add `std`, VS has no questions, g++ requires `cmath`.

Same goes for `system`: `system("foo")` for instance. No problem with VS compiler, but g++ again requires `std`.

And it's not some implied `using namespace std` in VS, since other functions (like `cout`) wouldn't compile without `std`.

So, are there some specific functions VS compiler includes from `std` by default? Is there a list of them somewhere? Or is something else going on here?

Comment: Library headers are allowed to include other library headers; which headers include which is unspecified. It would seem that in MSVC implementation, `iostream` includes `math.h` and/or `cmath`. You should explicitly include the necessary headers for any standard library feature you use.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found half of the question,
[Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) was right.

`math.h` and `cmath` are implemented differently in Visual C++, the first one has `int abs(int)`, the second overloaded it for other types. No std required.
iostream includes cmath.
oh my foo...

Comment: As I see it, this information should be included in an edit to your question, but not in the answer section.